# SQL BETWEEN Time doesn't show results?

Tags: sql

I want to find BETWEEN time but not show result.im share database  please share valuable idea....

****SQL code****

```
  SELECT *
        FROM ci_time_slot
        WHERE type like '%B%'
          and sloat_name BETWEEN '8:00 AM' and '12:00 PM'
```

**table**

```
id   sloat_name     type
1    8:00 AM        A,B,C,D
2    8:15 AM        A
3    8:30 AM        A,B
4    8:45 AM        A,C
5    9:00 AM        A,B,D
6    9:15 AM        A
7    9:30 AM        A,B,C
8    9:45 AM        A
9    10:00 AM       A,B,D
10   10:15 AM       A,C
11   10:30 AM       A,B
12   10:45 AM       A
13   11:00 AM       A,B,C,D
14   11:15 AM       A
15   11:30 AM       A,B
16   11:45 AM       A,C
17   12:00 PM       A,B,D
```

**need result**

**show this type of result depend on time**

```
id   sloat_name     type
1    8:00 AM        A,B,C,D
2    8:15 AM        A
3    8:30 AM        A,B
4    8:45 AM        A,C
5    9:00 AM        A,B,D
6    9:15 AM        A
7    9:30 AM        A,B,C
8    9:45 AM        A
9    10:00 AM       A,B,D
10   10:15 AM       A,C
11   10:30 AM       A,B
12   10:45 AM       A
13   11:00 AM       A,B,C,D
14   11:15 AM       A
15   11:30 AM       A,B
16   11:45 AM       A,C
17   12:00 PM       A,B,D
```

Comment: Column sloat_name data type?

Comment: Please specify RDBMS you use and provide some sample data and desired output. Date/time-related questions are heavily dependent on the RDBMS

Comment: Please share valuable table description

Comment: try `and sloat_name BETWEEN '08:00:00' and '12:00:00' `?

Comment: i using slot booking availability show between am to pm

Comment: doctor that time to this time availability.

Comment: Alter column data type to a proper date/time data type.

Comment: please edit my code and share valuable idea.

Comment: Please add data as text not image

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned yet which dbms are you using ,I'm using `MySQL` for demonstration. You have to cast sloat_name to time to use between.

Try :

```
SELECT c.*
FROM ci_time_slot c
WHERE type like '%B%'
and cast(sloat_name as time) between '08:00:00' and '12:00:00';
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> id    sloat_name  type
> 1      8:00 AM    A,B,C,D
> 3      8:30 AM    A,B
> 5      9:00 AM    A,B,D
> 7      9:30 AM    A,B,C
> 9     10:00 AM    A,B,D
> 11    10:30 AM    A,B
> 13    11:00 AM    A,B,C,D
> 15    11:30 AM    A,B
> 17    12:00 PM    A,B,D
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ee83e1be2a937598896fc1602de7e67c)

Comment: thanku for share valuable idea sir